# Getting error while parsing through driver.find_element()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, data-science, analysis

I am getting below error even after correcting the query, I have tried all the given solutions but the error is still same.

I am using 2 jupyter files, one is imported into the other and is used to extract data from the web

Attached error screenshot and the code snippet where the error is generated.

I have tried the possible solution from the web.

Code :

```py
def get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, path, slp_time):
    
    '''Gathers jobs as a dataframe, scraped from Glassdoor'''
    
    #Initializing the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    #Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
    #options.add_argument('headless')
    
    #Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)

    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword="' + keyword + '"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'
    driver.get(url)
    jobs = []

    while len(jobs) < num_jobs:  #If true, should be still looking for new jobs.

        #Let the page load. Change this number based on your internet speed.
        #Or, wait until the webpage is loaded, instead of hardcoding it.
        time.sleep(slp_time)

        #Test for the "Sign Up" prompt and get rid of it.
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[alt='Close']").click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass

        time.sleep(.1)

        try:
            driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[alt = 'Close']").click()#clicking to the X.
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        
        #Going through each job in this page
        job_buttons = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "jl")  #jl for Job Listing. These are the buttons we're going to click.
        for job_button in job_buttons:  

            print("Progress: {}".format("" + str(len(jobs)) + "/" + str(num_jobs)))
            if len(jobs) >= num_jobs:
                break

            job_button.click()  #You might 
            time.sleep(1)
            collected_successfully = False
```

Call made here :

```py
df = get_jobs("data scientist", 15, False, path, 10)
```

Error Encoutered:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5364\40834992.py in <module>
----> 1 df = get_jobs("data scientist", 15, False, path, 10)

~\Documents\ds_salary_proj\glassdoor_scrapper.ipynb in get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, path, slp_time)
     36     "    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)\n",
     37     "\n",
---> 38     "    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword=\"' + keyword + '\"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'\n",
     39     "    driver.get(url)\n",
     40     "    jobs = []\n",

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the desired element and the complete error stacktrace.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. There are too many things missing for us to actually run this code and reproduce the behavior locally.